# How to set predefined macro key for NSLog(@"mytext") typing and cursor focus and selected to edit between " mytext "

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios4

How to set predefined macro key for `NSLog(@"mytext")` typing and cursor focus and selected to  edit between `" mytext "`

Please we use NSLog almost everywhere.

So if we get to type nslog then we will be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out debugging techniques with `NSLog` [in this article](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/). Also I've written a short article on [how to create autocompletion](http://walkingsmarts.com/xcode-macro-specification-for-dlog-and-alog/) using macros in the first article.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a feature automatically supported in Xcode, but if you run Xcode 3, you can use [Completion Dictionary by Objective Development](http://www.obdev.at/products/completion-dictionary/index.html) (it's an excellent tool) to achieve the same effect. If you run Xcode 4 (which doesn't support Completion Dictionary), you're going to have to use a general macro application, such as [TextExpander by SmileOnMyMac](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) or [Typinator by Ergonis](http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a C macro you could do something like this:

```
#define nslog(x) NSLog(@ "before " #x " after" );
```

Then you can use it in your program like this:

```
nslog(test)
```

Which will print out:

```
before test after
```

Comment: then look at @Itai Ferber's answer.